# What is a container in JUnit 5

Tags: java, junit5

The current https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide uses the term container around 50 times without defining it.

What is the difference between test class and container? Can one container be in more than one class? Can one class has more than one container? (for example nested classes).

Comment: Have you already taken a look here https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/ ?

Comment: The class is a container, but so can a test method be, especially with a parameterized test method (i.e. using an `@CsvSource` for instance).

Comment: @mrkernelpanic that is definitely another animal :)

Answer (score 4):

Let me chime in as one of the original members of the JUnit 5 team...

JUnit 5, as a platform, allows deeply nested trees of containers and tests. You can even have nodes that are both a test (= it makes sense to run it individually) and a container (= it has children). At the root of any testengine‘s Test tree is always the engine container.
There’s one important thing to know: Containers without children that are not themselves also tests will be pruned and not run!

As for Jupiter you have classes and nested classes as containers and test methods as tests. Consider the case of dynamic tests, though, where the annotated method is a test, I think, but it also creates a lot of children which are themselves tests. So it’s also a container.

Other test engines might decide to create containers for the packages and parent packages as well.

Comment: Thanks Johanes! Some follow up questions:
1)  how BeforeAll/BeforeEach and other methods are handled in terms of test/container?
2) There must be some classes/interfaces in API that relate to this test/container paradigm, could you point me at them?

Comment: As far as I remember HierarchicalTestEngine contains all the abstract execution logic. The lifecycle annotations are resolved during the recovery phase. But that all might have changed in the last two years that I haven’t looked at the code.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that container here is something containing tests :))

If you debug an `executionStarted` method in any listener you will see that top level container called "[engine:junit-jupiter]" (for the standard runner, or any other engine name you're using).

Then you'll see a test classes (each of them is container). If you're using "nested" (I mean `@Nested` tests) feature, your upper level tests will be also shown as container.

You can add more levels by creating your own engine and overriding test discovery mechanism.

Comment: yes, it was my "basic" understanding is. But I am just wondering, what are distinctions from test class, why the new term container. 

If the whole run is always a container, which contains test classes (containers), which contains tests -  is a good example of that distinction. Are there more of them? 
Is BeforeEach a part of the "test" or do they belong to container? 
And Before All?

Comment: BeforeEach is not a part of test - it's a "Callback". and it's not belong to container. Junit 5 is built as a  set of APIs. The platform is open. So, as I said, you can implement your own engine with another definition of container (!=TestClass). I think, the right place to get the best answer is a Junit Team gitHub :)

Comment: That's interesting. So there may be code, which is neither part of a test nor of a container. What happens if this part has fail (assertion or exception) - how the reporting should work?

I've actually created the issue, asking for explanation ;-) https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/2205

Comment: I've already solved it (reporting from infra code). a bit complicated, using an extra listener. Do you have this question here?

Comment: No, I haven't. I don't have some specific problem yet, but it is helpful to understand the concepts of the framework I am using.

Comment: One more good example ;). When running with @Parametrized, your test method becomes container and each invocation with particular permutation turns to it's child.

Answer (score -4):

A test class is basically a simple java class where you write all your test cases/methods(with @Test annotations).

---

A test container is kind of a sand box where your test cases will run . The 
@RunWith annotation creates that test container for mocking.

Doing something like :

---

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Test {
@Test
public void test(){
//your test
}
}
```

---

SpringJUnit4ClassRunner allow you to deploy your test in your container.

Other popular test containers are mentioned below.

1. MockitoJUnitRunner
2. HierarchicalContextRunner
3. Avh4's Nested
4. NitorCreation's NestedRunner
5. Arquillian

Comment: The question is about JUnit5 how does an answer to JUnit4 help this?